# Всплывающее окно на кнопки

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать чтобы такое же всплывающее окно которое выводится при наведение на кнопку 1 выводилось и при наведение на кнопку 2.При наведение на кнопку 1 пишется кнопка 1 а при наведение на кнопку 2 пишется кнопка 2.

```js
   function v45() {

  bt11 = document.createElement('BUTTON'); // создание кнопки
  bt11.id = 'cmd6'; // её id 

  bt11.textContent = 'Кнопка 2'; // её текст
  
  document.body.appendChild(bt11); // нужно для добавления
  var a = 6;
  var b = 2;
  bt11.title = 'количество очков ' + a + " " + b;
  bt11.onclick = function() { // функция при клике на неё

  }
}

v45();
```

```css
#i-have-a-tooltip {
  width:350px;
  font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-weight:100;
  font-size:20px;
  text-align:center;
  padding:50px;
  margin:100px auto;
  background:white;
  position:relative;
  border-radius:5px;
  box-shadow:10px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}

#i-have-a-tooltip:before {
  content:attr(data-description);
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display:block;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  color:white;
  padding:20px;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:-30px;
  margin-left:-100px;
  width:200px;
  height:65px;
  line-height:25px;
  border-radius:5px;
  opacity:0;
  transition:.25s ease-in-out;
}

#i-have-a-tooltip:after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:35px;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-8px;
  height:0;
  width:0;
  border-left:8px solid transparent;
  border-right:8px solid transparent;
  border-top:8px solid rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  transition:.25s ease-in-out;
  opacity:0;
}

#i-have-a-tooltip:hover:before {
  opacity:1;
  top:-50px;
}

#i-have-a-tooltip:hover:after {
  opacity:1;
  top:15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  
  
  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  
</head>

<body>

  <div id="i-have-a-tooltip" data-description="Кнопка 1">
  Кнопка . <br> 1.
</div>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function v45() {
  bt11 = document.createElement('BUTTON'); // создание кнопки
  bt11.id = 'cmd6'; // её id 
  bt11.textContent = 'Кнопка 2'; // её текст
  
  bt11.className = "i-have-a-tooltip";
  bt11.dataset.description = "Кнопка 2";
  
  document.body.appendChild(bt11); // нужно для добавления
  var a = 6;
  var b = 2;
  bt11.title = 'количество очков ' + a + " " + b;
  bt11.onclick = function() { // функция при клике на неё

  }
}

v45();
```

```css
.i-have-a-tooltip {
  width: 350px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

.i-have-a-tooltip:before {
  content: attr(data-description);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: -30px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 65px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

.i-have-a-tooltip:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-top: 8px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

.i-have-a-tooltip:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
  top: -50px;
}

.i-have-a-tooltip:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="i-have-a-tooltip" data-description="Кнопка 1">
  Кнопка . <br> 1.
</div>
```

Comment: Можете показать,как сделать чтобы при наведение на кнопку 1 выводится сообщения кнопка 1 ,а при наведение на кнопку 2 выводится сообщение кнопка 2?

Comment: @Ivan912 добавил

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: @Ivan912 Пожалуйста. Успехов!